# Unique representation in a particular generate subspace

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation, solution-verification, normed-spaces

Let $X$ be a normed linear space. Suppose that

$(a)$ $M$ is a closed subspace of $X$;

$(b)$ $x_0\in X\setminus M$, and

$(d)$ $d=\text{dist}(X,M)=\inf\{\rVert x_0-m\lVert\;m\in M\}$

We define $M_1=\text{span}\{M, x_0\}$, then each $x\in M_1$ can be written as $x=m_x+t_xx_0$ for some $m_x\in M$ and $t_x\in\mathbb{R}(\text{or}\;\mathbb{C})$.

I must prove that this representation is unique. Suppose that $$m_x+t_x x_0=n_x+s_x x_0\quad(m_x\ne n_x)\quad s_x\in\mathbb{R}\;\text{or}\;\mathbb{C},$$ then we have $$m_x-n_x=x_0(s_x-t_x)\in M$$ but then $$\frac{1}{s_x-t_x}(s_x-t_x)x_0=x_0\in M$$ Absurd! It's correct?

**Second proof**

We suppose that $$m_x+t_xx_0=n_x+s_x x_0\quad\text{where}\quad m_x,n_x\in M, t_x,s_x\in \mathbb{R}\;\text{or}\;\mathbb{C}$$ then,

$$(m_x-n_x)+(t_x-s_x)x_0=0\iff m_x=n_x\;\text{and}\quad(t_x-s_x)x_0=0.$$

Now $(t_x-s_x)x_0=0$ iff $t_x=s_x$ or $x_0=0$, but if $x_0=0$ then $x_0\in M$, absurd. Correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the logical arguments follows, however the thesis is not being properly negated.

Note that, to show that the representation is unique, is to show that both $m_x = n_x$ **and** $s_x = t_x$. It happens that the the negation of this statement is $m_x \neq n_x$ **or** $s_x \neq t_x$, and you are just assuming that $m_x \neq n_x$.

Comment: you are right! Now, if we start that there are two representatin without supposing that $m_x\ne n_x$, how can we show the statement?

Comment: I modified the post adding another proof, is it correct now?

Comment: The first proof is fine; you just need to fix the thesis negation and it will follow as it is. Regarding to the second proof is not clear why the biconditional holds. Aside, have in mind that editing a question after it is answered is not fair to the users who answered it and therefore not seen with good eyes by the MSE community.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. But I don't understand how I have to fix the proof. Could you suggest something to me?

Comment: You just need to change the hypothesis of the first proof from "$m_x \neq n_x$ " to "$m_x \neq n_x$ or $s_x \neq t_x$". This single change is enough for you to have a perfectly fine [proof by contradiction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_contradiction).